Python and win32gui/win32api: Accessing bits of a PyBITMAP
Trying to write python code to capture screen. The following, a direct conversion from C-code, works like a charm:
hdcScreen = win32gui.GetDC(0)
hdcMemDC = win32gui.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);

rcClient = win32gui.GetClientRect(win32gui.GetDesktopWindow())

# Create a compatible bitmap from the Window DC.
hbmScreen = win32gui.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, rcClient[2] - rcClient[0], rcClient[3] - rcClient[1]);

# Select the compatible bitmap into the compatible memory DC.
win32gui.SelectObject(hdcMemDC, hbmScreen)

win32gui.BitBlt(hdcMemDC, 0, 0, rcClient[2] - rcClient[0], rcClient[3] - rcClient[1], hdcScreen, 0, 0, win32con.SRCCOPY)

bmpScreen = win32gui.GetObject(hbmScreen)

bmpScreen now contains an instance of PyBITMAP with all fields filled correctly:

But from this point, I am just playing by the ear and need help.
The code
addr = id(bmpScreen)
fmt="llllllll" # 8 l's
bminfo_buf = win32gui.PyGetMemory(addr, struct.calcsize(fmt))

unpacked_list = struct.unpack_from(fmt, bminfo_buf)
print(unpacked_list)

produces the tuple
(1, 0, -786488688, 2046, 0, 1920, 1080, 7680)
and with
fmt="lllllll" # 7 l's
(1, 0, -785767792, 2046, 0, 1920, 1080)
So fmt is probably incorrect, and I don't know how to get to the bits.
Please nudge me in the right direction. Thanks!
